# What are these extra parameters when calling SendInput via win32API

Tags: ruby, winapi, struct, msdn

I am interested in sending key input through Ruby using the win32API.
I have found the function that I would like to call: [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx)

MSDN describes the signature as follows:

```
UINT WINAPI SendInput(
  _In_  UINT nInputs,
  _In_  LPINPUT pInputs,
  _In_  int cbSize
);
```

And INPUT looks like

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  };
} INPUT, *PINPUT;
```

So there's one integer that I need showing the input type.
Since I'm interested in keyboard events, I looked at the `KEYBDINPUT` struct

```
typedef struct tagKEYBDINPUT {
  WORD      wVk;
  WORD      wScan;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  DWORD     time;
  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
} KEYBDINPUT, *PKEYBDINPUT;
```

And there's another 5 arguments: two 16-bit integers and three 32-bit integers.

Now, from what I have gathered, `SendInput` takes an integer, a pointer to an INPUT struct, and an integer representing the size of the INPUT struct. Creating the `Win32API` object looks like

```
SendInput = Win32API.new("User32", "SendInput", "LPL", "L")
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
```

Now I build my INPUT struct:

```
input = [INPUT_KEYBOARD, 0x5A, 0, 0, 0, 0].pack('ISSIII')
```

First argument is the input type, followed by the five arguments for the `KEYBDINPUT` struct: the virtual keycode for the key I want to press, and some other flags that I don't need for testing purposes.

So I run it:

```
SendInput.call(1, input, input.size)
```

Nothing happens.

When I check GetLastError, it returns an [error code of 87](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), which means there were invalid arguments.

I then decided to search around and found that someone else is building their input struct like this:

```
input = [INPUT_KEYBOARD, 0x5A, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].pack('ISSIIIII')
```

I tried running it, and it executes successfully!

Difference? There's two extra arguments for the input.
Now I am confused: what are these two extra arguments for the input struct?
Is there something that I'm missing when I was reading the docs?

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the `ULONG_POINTER` type, but when I look up the data types, it's a 32-bit integer.

Reference: http://www.dsprobotics.com/support/viewtopic.php?p=7110&sid=cd256b848d00e64a2e74e093863f837f#p7110

Comment: Exact same situation I had but with js-ctypes, thank you very much for sharing!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call takes a `union` of those structs, I would wager it has something to do with that.

Looks like `MOUSEINPUT` is larger than `KEYBOARDINPUT`:

```
typedef struct tagMOUSEINPUT {
  LONG      dx;
  LONG      dy;
  DWORD     mouseData;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  DWORD     time;
  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
} MOUSEINPUT, *PMOUSEINPUT;
```

Dunno for sure though, that seems like a pretty terrifying way to bridge those calls!

edit: Yeah, looks like using that `MOUSEINPUT` size, you end up w/28 bytes of data sent to the function, which is what `pack('ISSIIIII')` would net you.

Comment: I briefly read about unions to get an idea of what they are for, but didn't read about how they are actually implemented. But thinking about it, it makes sense though: if you allow different types of data in the same memory space, you'd need at least the size of the largest type...

Comment: @MxyL is your comment verified by anyone else like winapi experts? It makes sense, but I was just wondering if its verified, I had the same exact issue and fixed it by making my kyinput struct have same size as mouseinput struct.